# Notarize Qt app for Mac OS Catalina on Mojave

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I want to notarize an existing Qt app for Mac OSX.
I do not have an Apple Developer ID which makes things a bit harder, nevertheless, according to Apple's [workflow description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow#3087734), this should be possible.
I created a so called app-specific password (why is it app-specific? nobody asked me for the app's name when I created that password???)
This password I pass along with my apple-id into altool. 
I started by "hardening" my app with

```
codesign --deep -s "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" --options runtime --timestamp "my-app.app/"
```

Then I build my package as usual and put everything into a dmg.
XXXXXXXXXXXXX is a long number that I found next to my developer certificate (see below).

My problem: whenever I call

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app -t osx -f my-app.dmg --primary-bundle-id="com.bundle.app" -u "my-apple@id.net" -p "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

I get:

> The username my-apple@id.net is not a member of the provider

According to [this source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113798), this error means that the TeamID is not correct - but where does the TeamID come in anyhow? I found my Organization-ID in the certificate I identified with `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`. But where does this ID go to? Into the Info.plist? But which key?

If I put my local username or the app-specific-passwords user name behind `-u` instead of my apple id, I get

> *** Error: Unable to validate your application. This person is not active.

**EDIT:** Calling `iTMSTransporter -m provider -u my-apple@id.net -p @file:password.txt` gives

> Neither an encoding house user nor an iTunesConnect user was found. 
>   The error code is: 1080

So it looks as if `-u apple-id` is wrong, but what other user can I pass?

Comment: This [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113798) may be helpful

Comment: I tried iTMTransponder but got a very long log with error messages, which were equally unhelpful. I can attach them once I‘m back on my Mac.